# c - sockets, why do ip are sent in integer format?

Tags: c, sockets

## Question

I am wondering why do we connect to sockets by using functions like hton to take care of endianness when we could have sent the ip in plain char array.

Say we want to connect to 184.54.12.169

There is an explanation to this but I cannot figure out why we use integers instead of char, and so involving ourself in endianness hell.

I think char out_ip[] = "184.54.12.169" could have theoretically made it.

#### Please explain me the subtleties i don't get here.

Comment: Because size matters.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Isn't it possible to ask a question anymore on this site without being flushed out ? Nice..

Comment: I'm guessing because someone felt the question had been asked before. I think it is a reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks Claris for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [that's how an IP is transmitted in a packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure). The "www.xxx.yyy.zzz" string form is really just a human readable form of a 4 byte integer that allows us to see the hierarchical nature a little easier. Sending a whole string would take up a lot more space as well.

Comment: And there is a lot more in a packet than just the IP address.

Comment: @Jongware Did I imply that is the only part of a packet?

Comment: No, but the OP seemed unaware of all other data. I.e., just sending the IP address as a string would still need "endianness hell" for the remaining data.

Comment: @Jongware ah ok, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

The basic networking APIs are low level functions. These are very thin wrappers around kernel system calls. Removing these low level functions, forcing everything to use strings, would be rather bad for a low-level API like that, especially considering how tedious string handling is in C. As a concrete hurdle, even IP strings would not be fixed length, so handling them is a lot more complex than just plain 32 bit integers. And moving string handling to kernel is really quite against what kernel is supposed to be, handling arbitrary user strings is really user space problem.

So, you want to create higher-level functions which would accept strings and do the conversion in the library. But, adding such higher level "convenience" functions all over the place in the core libraries would bloat them, because certainly passing IP numbers is not the only place for such convenience. These functions would need to be maintained forever and included everywhere, after they became part of standard (official like POSIX, or de-facto) libraries.

So, removing the low-level functions is not really an option, and adding more functions for higher-level API in the same library is not a good option either.

So solution is to use another library to provide higher level networking API, which could for example handle address strings directly. Not sure what's out ther for C, but it's almost a given for other languages, which also have "real" strings built in so using them is not a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Say number 127536 that requires 7 bytes not four. In addition you need to parse it.

I.e. more efficient and do not have to deal with invalid values.

Comment: yes but 192.168.1.5 requires 4 * 4 bytes, no ? It would only require 11 char bytes. EDIT : no, i am wrong, it is 4 bytes sorry